# While statement timing out

Tags: php, while-loop, timeout

I'm trying to implement pagination for a search result. The following code works perfectly:

```
        echo "<p>" . $data['meta']['total'] . " properties found. (search " . $data['meta']['searchId'] . ")</p>\n";

        $pages = $data['meta']['total'] / $count;
        $pages = ceil($pages);

        echo "<p>" . $pages . "</p>\n";
```

However, if I add in the following, I get a timeout:

```
        $page = 1;

        echo "<p>";
        while ($page <= $pages); {
            echo $page++ . " ";
        }
        echo "</p>\n";
```

No doubt I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What is the output of: `echo $page; echo $pages;` if you put this before the while loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
while ($page <= $pages); {
                     //^ See this empty statement here!
    echo $page++ . " ";
}
```

Your while loop loops trough a empty statement so no statement is going to increment `$page`. So your curly brackets are just a normal code block, in order to get your while loop working just remove the semicolon like this:

```
while ($page <= $pages) {
    echo $page++ . " ";
}
```

Comment: @Badger You're welcome! (I also didn't saw it the first time :D)